# Custom field uniqness validation for classes implementing common interface Hibernate + Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm trying to make a custom validation (checking if an email is already present in the database). For single class my annotation is working fine but I need to make this validation work for two objects implementing common interface. I have *User* interface and *Visitor* and *Exhibitor* classes which are implementing it.

Here is my annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface UniqueEmail {

    String message() default "Email is already existing!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is Validator class

```
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueEmail uniqueEmail) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        return !userService.isEmailPresent(email);
    }
}
```

UserService is a common interface of VisitorService and ExhibitorService

```
public interface UserService {

    boolean isEmailPresent(String email);
}
```

And it's implementation...

```
@Service
public class VisitorService implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    VisitorDao visitorDao;

    @Override
    public boolean isEmailPresent(String email) {
        try {
            return !visitorDao.findAllByEmail(email).isEmpty();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm getting NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at pl.com.sremski.testapp.validators.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at pl.com.sremski.testapp.validators.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:10)
```

Any ideas what's the reason? I was trying to debug and UserService is null... but I'm trying to add a new visitor so it should use VisitorService. Please help.

Comment: It does not look like `userService` is getting initialized anywhere.

Comment: So how to initialize it? I can't just @Autowire because it won't know which implementation it should use.

Comment: Have you considered using `@Qualifier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by specifing exact implementation in annotation's parameter

```
@UniqueEmail(service = VisitorService.class)
```

and then creating it's instance in

```
@Override
public void initialize(UniqueEmail uniqueEmail) {
}
```

However I had to separate all Spring-based validation from Hibernate's entity to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have two different annotations with different `@Qualifier()` marked beans, you can consider to choose that bean in runtime using application context. But injecting whole Spring context to your business logic is considered as a very bad practice: 
1) Mixing infrastructure (your WHOLE infrastructure) with business processes makes your code hard to understand and decouple. 
2) It is hard to unit test this, need to mock the context object instead of your services. 
But after using [Google Guice DI](https://github.com/google/guice) I found myself in using `Provider<Service>` pattern, because injecting spring into spring is OK. So you can create a class like:

```
@Service
class UserServiceProvider<T extends UserService> implements Provider<T> {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

    public UserService get(Class<T> exactServiceType) {
        return (UserService) context.getBean(exactServiceType);
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a much better "Spring way" to do this, but this code is easy to understand and maintain. Works lile a `Scope.Prototype` bean, but a bit more flexible. 
[Google Guice Provider tutorial](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings)

**EDIT**:
Spring has a similar interface `FactoryBean<T>` and it has an enhanced handling, because DI will inject not the factory, but what factory provides. 
But the one problem is you can't do it with some condition. 
[Simple example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean)